# Cannot get android studio app to start login screen after initial splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to java coding and Android Studio, so please bear with me.  However, I am trying to get a login screen to start after the splash screen and the app crashes after the splash screen.  The splash screen works no problem.  Anyways, here is the first set of code and this is the splash screen code in Main activity.

```
package com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation mine = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition);
        final Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginPageActivity.class);
        //set duration ... 1 second ... :p
        mine.setDuration(1000);
        tv.startAnimation(mine);
        iv.startAnimation(mine);
        //make a thread to go to second activity...
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(go);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }


    }
```

this is the Login Page activity called "LoginPageActivity.java" that I would like to have the app go to after the splash screen.

```
package com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import static com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.R.layout.activity_login_page;

public class LoginPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_login_page);

    findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);

}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.textViewSignUp:

                    startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class));

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the androidmanifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx">

    <application
        android:name=".Database"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat error

```
1-28 12:55:33.490 7647-7670/com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
                                                                              Process: com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx, PID: 7647
                                                                              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx/com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1932)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
                                                                                  at com.example.mike.safetychecker.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:39)
```

Also if needed the file activity_login_page.xml code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginPageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Hi, Welcome to Safety xxxxxx Please Login or Signup"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.995"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="398dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text=" email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="270dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:text=" Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="336dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="219dp"
        android:layout_height="229dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextEmail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/safetyxxxx" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSignUp"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Do Not Have An Account?  Click Here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="459dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also there is this transition.xml file contained in a anim folder that might help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    />
```

Comment: why are you **LoginPageActivity**  in intent filter.

Comment: There are two LAUNCHER activities which may causing to crash your app, make DEFAULT the second activity.

Comment: @wolfgang as you're new to Android, please learn immediately the [proper way](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857) to use a splash screen (activity)

Comment: Thanks Alessio for the link, I will have a look and make the necessary changes.

Comment: Make a separate method or See my updated post now, It will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try to open your `LoginPageActivity` like this way

**Paste this code**

```
openActivity();
```

**instead of this**

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(go);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

**and put this method**

```
public void openActivity()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
                         startActivity(go);
                        finish();

                    }
                }, 5000);
    }
```

**import this packages**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
```

and also mention in your manifest like this

```
<activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Comment: Where would I place this code exactly in the mainactivity 
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginPageActivity.class);
                 startActivity(go);
                finish();

            }
        }, 5000);
and what code would I keep?

Comment: So, now it has a red underline for the word Handler and says it cannot resolve symbol Handler and for the postDelayed portion it is also underlined red and says Cannot resolve method 'postDelayed(anonymous java.lang.Runnable, int)'

Comment: also void comes back with an illegal type message

Comment: Thanks Raja, this was the answer right here.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. Almost all of your system-related classes have to be declared in it, this includes Activities, Services, BroadCast Receivers. You can read up on how Manifest works over [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Back to your problem, you can fix it by add the following line **inside the application tag** in your Android Manifest. Remove any intent filters you have applied to it

```
<activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will have a look at that.  However,, this solution did not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Because there is always remains only one LAUNCHER activity in application. And also intent filter is wrong there.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it did not work same error and problem

Answer (score 0):

change LAUNCHER TO DEFAULT in your mainfest, Two launcher is not possible at same time  (Assuming MainActivity as LAUNCHER)

```
</activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it did not work same error and problem

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

instead of

```
 <activity android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,com.example.xxxx.safetyxxxxxxx.LoginPageActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }, 5000);
```

//where 5000 is the delayed time

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it did not work same error and problem

Comment: use handler when passing intent